# Python, AWS S3: how to read file with jsons

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an JSONs files in S3 bucket(file with each row - json).
And I'm having troubles correctly read them..
What I'm doing:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, Key=key)
file = response['Body']
for line in file:
    data_json = json.loads(line, encoding='utf-8')
```

In this case it ignores `\n` and read bunch of text as a line.

How to properly read all jsons from each line in a file?

Example of an input file content (a file with  number of jsons as a separate row):

```
{"notificationItems":[{"NotificationRequestItem":{"eventCode":"PENDING","AccountCode":"A001US","amount":{"currency":"USD","value":111},"success":"true","method":"xxx","reference":"43535353","date":"2021"}}],"go":"true"}
{"notificationItems":[{"NotificationRequestItem":{"eventCode":"PENDING","AccountCode":"A002US","amount":{"currency":"USD","value":111},"success":"true","method":"xxx","reference":"43535353","date":"2021"}}],"go":"true"}
...
{"notificationItems":[{"NotificationRequestItem":{"eventCode":"PENDING","AccountCode":"A003US","amount":{"currency":"USD","value":111},"success":"true","method":"xxx","reference":"43535353","date":"2021"}}],"go":"true"}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? This looks fine assuming the file is `jsonl` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boto3's `get_object` returns a [StreamingBody](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) object as the value for `Body` of the return dictionary.

One of the methods of the object is an `iter_lines` method that allows you to iterate over the lines of the response as it's read.  You can call `json.loads` on  each line from there:

```python
for line in file.iter_lines():
    data = json.loads(line)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get object returns a aws `botocore.response.StreamingBody` You need to do a `.read()` on if your function taking it cannot take a raw byte stream ( see [this documentation](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) )

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=SOURCE, Key=key)['body'].read()
for line in response:
     json_data = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: No, `.read()` returns you binary and it would work if I had just single json, but I have a file with a number of jsons separated by newline.

Comment: Seems like I can use `iter_lines` instead of `.read()`. Description is very poor.